# How to disable Symfony 3 builtin server logging during PHPUnit testing?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I setup PHPUnit testing for my Symfony 3 REST API.
During test executing, the built-in server spits its logs on the console and these logs get mixed up with the PHPUnit logs, which makes everything unreadable :

```
Testing Project Test Suite
.[Thu Dec 27 00:35:05 2018] 127.0.0.1:43090 [200]: /medialinks/1
.[Thu Dec 27 00:35:06 2018] 127.0.0.1:43196 [500]: /medialinks/1
E                                                                 3 / 3 (100%)
```

How can I avoid it ?